# Next.js "API resolved without sending a response for /api/v1/welcome, this may result in stalled requests"

Tags: typescript, api, next.js

I am using Next.js API routes in welcome.js
However, whenever I send a get request at the url, I get the "API resolved without sending a response for /api/v1/welcome, this may result in stalled requests" error.

When my partner runs the same code it works perfectly fine for him and he is able to get the data but I get the error on my end. This makes me think its not my code but maybe another problem - does anyone have any idea what the issue could be?

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { protect } from '../../../server/protect';

export default protect(function handler(
 req: NextApiRequest,
 res: NextApiResponse
) {
 switch (req.method) {
   case 'GET':
     return res
       .status(200)
       .json(
         'Thanks for applying to HackBeanpot 2048! <sample welcome message>'
       );
   case 'POST':
     return res.status(201).send(undefined);
   default:
     return res.status(405).setHeader('Allow', 'GET, POST').send(undefined);
 }
});
```

The protect function used is the following:

```
import { NextApiHandler } from 'next';
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/client';

export function protect(handler: NextApiHandler): NextApiHandler {
  return async (req, res) => {
    const session = await getSession({ req });
    if (session) {
      await handler(req, res);
    } else {
      res.status(401);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: @juliomalves Yep! I just added in the function into my post!

Comment: Try adding a `return` when calling `await handler(req, res)`, e.g., `return await handler(req, res)`.

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks for the suggestion but I'm still getting the error unfortunately

Comment: **RESOLVED!! - The problem was I didn't call .send() in the else statement